# SQL: Sort a table by the first relation to a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I have a Many-to-Many relationship between two tables. I'd like to sort the first table by the first relationship with the second table and only return a single result from that table. This is on SQL Server. I'd like something like this:

```
SELECT a.retrieve_me
FROM table_A AS a
JOIN table_B AS b ON a.foo = b.foo
JOIN table_C AS c ON b.bar = c.bar
ORDER BY c.sort_me
```

Unfortunately it returns *MN(k)* results, where *M* is the count of "table_A" and *N(k)* is the number of relations of a single row *k* with "table_C." To have it return just the results I wanted without post filtering I tried using `DISTINCT` on the `SELECT` clause and using `TOP(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_A)` but neither are valid syntax.

Any ideas? Hoping I can make this as performant as possible.

**EDIT:**

For clarity

```
table A
------------
"joe" 1
"betty" 2
"george" 3

table B
------------
1 2
1 3
2 3
2 4
3 1

table C
------------
1 "ashton"
2 "harding"
3 "spring"
4 "merry lane"
```

I'd like the results returned in the order of "george", "joe", and "betty" which is in the order (george -> ashton, joe -> harding, betty -> merry lane.)

Comment: ... Could we get some sample data and desired results?  As @Dumitrescu  says, I'm having a little trouble following what you want.

Comment: @X-Zero sorry to be so hard to follow. One sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you need, cause I think is very hard to follow you .. this should do it:

```
SELECT a.nm
FROM tablea a
cross apply (select top 1 * 
         from tableb b
         join tablec c on b.id2 = c.id
         where a.id = b.id1
         order by c.nm) bc
order by bc.nm
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/661c0/5/0

Comment: No .. but was damn close :))). From what I understood on your initial problem, the c table was creating multiple rows not the b table. N(k) I believe should be the number of single rows in C with table b. Cause in c you have distinct rows. Anyway .. check now the update.